# Split literal path to get file name

Tags: powershell

How to get file name from literal path via split-path?
Why literalPath parameter set don't have -Leaf parameter?

```
Split-Path -LiteralPath "D:\myDir\file.txt" -Leaf
```

**file.txt** expected

Comment: Because there is a difference between these parameters (**-Path** and **-LiteralPath**).

Comment: `-Path` is read as literal afaik, so there is no need to worry about it

Comment: @Olaf , yes, because -LiteralPath don't parse wild cards. I told about difference of this parameters.

Comment: Then why `Split-Path -Path "D:\[*myDir*]\file.txt" -Leaf` does work ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon , you mean that this phrase from the documentation "*Specifies the paths to be split. Wildcard characters are permitted.*" is a lie?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an **unfortunate bug** that `-LiteralPath` doesn't work with switches such as `-Leaf`, up to at least PowerShell 7.2.4 - see [GitHub issue #8751](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8751).

However, the bug is benign, because it is fine to use the (possibly positionally implied) `-Path` instead, because **the usual distinction between `-Path`** (potentially [wildcard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards)-based paths) and **`-LiteralPath`** (verbatim paths) ***by default* does *not* apply to the purely textual processing that `Split-Path` performs**, as [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out.

In other words: The following should work as intended (implicitly binds the file path to the `-Path` parameter, positionally):

```bash
Split-Path "D:\myDir\file.txt" -Leaf # -> 'file.txt'
```

Conversely, this means that - by default - `Split-Path` does *not* resolve wildcard-based paths - purely textual splitting occurs:

```bash
# NO wildcard resolution (matching), despite (implied) use of -Path
Split-Path "D:\myDir\*.txt" -Leaf   # -> '*.txt'
```

If **wildcard resolution** is needed, combined the (possibly implied) `-Path` parameter with the **`-Resolve` switch**:

```bash
# Wildcard resolution (matching), due to use of -Resolve with (implied) -Path
Split-Path -Resolve "D:\myDir\*.txt" -Leaf   # -> 'foo.txt', 'bar.txt', ....
```

Note that **the distinction between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` *does* matter *when combined with `-Resolve`***:

- With `-Path`, `-Resolve` performs wildcard resolution *and* uses the *full paths* of the matching files and/or directories for splitting, if any; if there are no matches, there is *no output*.
- With `-LiteralPath`, `-Resolve` *only* resolves the verbatim input path(s) to a *full path* and uses the full path for splitting; if the path doesn't exist, a non-terminating *error* is reported.

Comment: So **-Path** works like **-LiterPath**, and **-Path** parameter does not accept wildcards, even though it is specified in the documentation?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-5.1#example-2-display-file-names - perfect example)) What a problem for microsoft to delete this example, and fix documentation?)

Comment: Sorry, @Lexxy - and thanks for the link: it showed me that it's sufficient to add `-Resolve` in order to get wildcard resolution - please see my update.

Comment: @Lexxy, please see my latest update re `-Resolve` - it turns out that with `-Resolve` the distinction between `-Path` and `-LiteralPath` _does_ matter.